# Generate a random six-figure string in base 32?

Tags: javascript

As the title says: I'd like to generate a random six-figure string in Crockford's [base 32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#Crockford.27s_Base32) in JavaScript.

I currently generate a random six-figure number using this:

```
function genRandNum() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 900000) + 100000;
}
```

But base 32 would be cooler!

Could anyone recommend an efficient way to do this, other than just picking randomly from an array of characters six times to build up a string?

Comment: Have you actually tried to make a `getRandStr()` function using Crockford's `base 32` method?

Comment: No - not homework! And I don't want to be lazy, just wanted advice on the best way to approach this :) @Javed if you think that is the best way to do it, then I will write it, and post it as an answer - let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Number.toString(32)` will return the 32-bit representation of a number. This isn't Crockford's 32-bit representation (it uses `0123456789abcdefghijklmonpqrstuv` instead of Crockford's `0123456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstvwxyz`), but it can be changed very easily since the number's random anyway:

```
var key = {
    'i': 'w',
    'l': 'x',
    'o': 'y',
    'u': 'z'
};
var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random()*1e9);
alert(randomInt.toString(32).replace(/[ilou]/, function (a) { 
    return key[a]; 
}));
```